# How to get the browser's default font family in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and maybe this question is trivial, but I have googled a little and I didn't find what I'm looking for.

I have declared a font-family for all my site. Now, I want to override the font family for some sections. I need the **browser's default font family**. How can I specify the browser's default font family in a css?

```
.browser-defatults {
   font-family: ?????
}
```

Maybe I need to ignore all styles, how could I do this?

Comment: If you want the default for each browser, just don't set it in CSS

Comment: @m.edmondson: In this case I need something to ignore CSS. Do you know how?

Comment: Can you perhaps explain your problem more fully?  If you want a style you set it, if you want to ignore it you don't.

Comment: @m.edmondson He needs a custom font for everything, except some items. "Don't set it" may not be an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I know CSS doesn't offer an option to *ignore all previous user styles* for a property.

A work-around to your problem may be to use a [generic font-family](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#value-def-generic-family),

```
font-family: serif;
```

and let the browser choose.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good answer. Unfortunately my first test (Linux/Ubuntu/Firefox) did not returned the default font.

Comment: Having just looked through the w3schools website I must agree this is probably the best way.  Set it to something that looks like it could be the default (doesn't matter either way)

Comment: @Daniel Peñalba The short answer to what you are trying to achieve is: You can't. What I offered is just something that may help you, or lead you in a good direction.

Comment: Problem with this is that it selects the browser's default ***serif*** font; what if I had selected a sans-serif as my default? CSS has no way to specify to use the user's font preference and this is as close as it gets.  CSS needs a generic font of "default".

Comment: @LawrenceDol What if there was a font on the user's system called default? An entirely new syntax would have to be created to accommodate `default` value for this property.

Comment: @hrj That syntax is already there with quotes and unquoted font names.