# What is the defaul font face in HTML

Tags: html

What is the default font face set, if you don't specifically set the font? 
It seems to be Calibri, is this right or is this because of my browser?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508167/css-how-to-get-the-browsers-default-font-family

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML does not have a default font face. If you don't style your HTML document, the presentation is controlled by the browser defaults.

To eliminate differences between browsers, various Reset CSS scripts exist.

Answer (score 2):

HTML is a language your browser interprets to bring you webpages. Therefore, your browser has a default font face and that is what is shown if there isn't a directive to change the font from inside the HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Every browser has it's own "User Agent Style Sheet" which controls default formatting of all elements. For more in-depth reading on this subject: [User Agent Style Sheet Basics](http://meiert.com/en/blog/20070922/user-agent-style-sheets/)

This browser-defined style sheet defines how all elements appear before any further formatting is applied. As soon as you start defining styles then they are over-ridden.

Note that while every browser has it's own default style sheet, user agent style sheets are often defined by assistive technologies to help people who are color-blind, visually impaired, etc. So you can not assume that every Chrome has the same default user agent sheet. Theme/skinning software also often over-rides these style sheets as well.

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on your browser and OS. As you see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp), it is *not specified* by default.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answers say, there is no default HTML font. Each browser has its own default styles. You may want to [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214378/how-can-i-locate-the-default-style-sheet-for-a-browser) to learn more about which font is decided by each browser as default.