# Can't rewrite css style font:inherit to browser's user agent style

Tags: html, css, wordpress, input, fonts

I need customise wordpress theme according to main magento site. For having absolutely the same header in wordpress blog and main magento site. So I've created child theme and try override css property to use user agent style:

```
input {
    font:inherit;
}
```

like

```
input {
    font:initial;
}
```

But it does not work.

**UPDATE 1:**
I need override **font:inherit;** to default browser style.

**UPDATE 2:**
Actualy I need override

font-family:inherit;

but
font-family:initial;

does not do that it makes font-family: 'Times New Roman'; ,but I need browser default font, in chrome it is Arial, I can't write just Arial cuz other browsers has different default fonts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [css: how to get the browser's default font family](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508167/css-how-to-get-the-browsers-default-font-family)

Comment: The default font for text inputs is `small-caption`, so just write `font:small-caption;`. If you need a different font size, you will need to explicitly write `font:small-caption; font-size:inherit;` (or whatever size you need).

Comment: it does not work, it makes font - font-family: 'Segoe UI';